# Printing matching properties in DBpedia query

Tags: properties, rdf, sparql, matching, dbpedia

The following query will search for matching subjects based on a list of properties and within a given distance. They are ranked by the number of matching properties (?numProperties), which is output as a number. How can I also print each of the properties that are matches?

[Run query](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=select%20%3Fsubject%20%28count%20%28%20distinct%20%3Fproperty%29%20as%20%3FnumProperties%29%20%3Flabel%20%3Flat%20%3Flong%20where%20%7B%0D%0Avalues%20%3Fproperty%20%7B%20dbpedia-owl%3Acrosses%20dbpedia-owl%3Avehicle%20dbpedia-owl%3Areopened%20dbpedia-owl%3Ayears%20dbpedia-owl%3Aaccess%20dbpedia-owl%3Athird%20dbpedia-owl%3Atime%20dbpedia-owl%3Aconstruction%20dbpedia-owl%3Aanniversary%20dbpedia-owl%3Aseries%20dbpedia-owl%3Alength%20dbpprop%3Asuspension%20dbpprop%3Abridge%20dbpprop%3Acrosses%20dbpprop%3ACity%20dbpprop%3Aconnecting%20dbpprop%3Alast%20dbpprop%3Athree%20dbpprop%3Asuspension%20dbpprop%3Abridges%20dbpprop%3Abuilt%20%7D%20%0D%0A%3Fsubject%20%3Fproperty%20%3Fobject%20.%0D%0A%3Fsubject%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20.%0D%0A%3Fsubject%20geo%3Alat%20%3Flat%20.%0D%0A%3Fsubject%20geo%3Along%20%3Flong%20.%0D%0AFILTER%20%28%3Flong%20%3E%20-74.490898%20%26%26%20%3Flong%20%3C%20%20-73.490898%20%26%26%20%3Flat%20%3E%20%2040.207222%20%20%26%26%20%3Flat%20%3C%20%2041.207222%20%20%29%20.%0D%0AFILTER%28langMatches%28lang%28%3Flabel%29%2C%22EN%22%29%29%20.%0D%0A%7D%20%0D%0Agroup%20by%20%3Fsubject%20%3Flabel%20%3Flat%20%3Flong%0D%0Aorder%20by%20desc%28%3FnumProperties%29%20%0D%0Alimit%2015)

```
select ?subject (count ( distinct ?property) as ?numProperties) ?label ?lat ?long where {
values ?property { dbpedia-owl:crosses dbpedia-owl:vehicle dbpedia-owl:reopened dbpedia-owl:years dbpedia-owl:access dbpedia-owl:third dbpedia-owl:time dbpedia-owl:construction dbpedia-owl:anniversary dbpedia-owl:series dbpedia-owl:length dbpprop:suspension dbpprop:bridge dbpprop:crosses dbpprop:City dbpprop:connecting dbpprop:last dbpprop:three dbpprop:suspension dbpprop:bridges dbpprop:built } 
?subject ?property ?object .
?subject rdfs:label ?label .
?subject geo:lat ?lat .
?subject geo:long ?long .
FILTER (?long > -74.490898 && ?long <  -73.490898 && ?lat >  40.207222  && ?lat <  41.207222  ) .
FILTER(langMatches(lang(?label),"EN")) .
} 
group by ?subject ?label ?lat ?long
order by desc(?numProperties) 
limit 15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
#-- I took the liberty of tidying up your query a bit.
#-- The key is to use the GROUP_CONCAT aggregate function.
select
  ?subject
  (count(distinct ?property) as ?numProperties)
  ?label
  ?lat
  ?long
  #-- concatenate distinct properties into a ', ' separated string
  (group_concat(distinct ?property;separator=', ') as ?properties)
where {
  values ?property {
    dbpedia-owl:crosses dbpedia-owl:vehicle dbpedia-owl:reopened
    dbpedia-owl:years dbpedia-owl:access dbpedia-owl:third
    dbpedia-owl:time dbpedia-owl:construction dbpedia-owl:anniversary
    dbpedia-owl:series dbpedia-owl:length dbpprop:suspension
    dbpprop:bridge dbpprop:crosses dbpprop:City dbpprop:connecting
    dbpprop:last dbpprop:three dbpprop:suspension
    dbpprop:bridges dbpprop:built
  } 
  ?subject ?property ?object ;
           rdfs:label ?label ;
           geo:lat ?lat ;geo:long ?long .
  FILTER ( -74.490898 < ?long && ?long < -73.490898 &&
            40.207222 < ?lat  && ?lat  <  41.207222 )
  FILTER(langMatches(lang(?label),"EN"))
} 
group by ?subject ?label ?lat ?long
order by desc(?numProperties) 
limit 15
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%0D%0A%20%20%3Fsubject%0D%0A%20%20%28count%28distinct%20%3Fproperty%29%20as%20%3FnumProperties%29%0D%0A%20%20%3Flabel%0D%0A%20%20%3Flat%0D%0A%20%20%3Flong%0D%0A%20%20%28group_concat%28distinct%20%3Fproperty%3Bseparator%3D%27%2C%20%27%29%20as%20%3Fproperties%29%0D%0Awhere%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20values%20%3Fproperty%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20dbpedia-owl%3Acrosses%20dbpedia-owl%3Avehicle%20dbpedia-owl%3Areopened%20dbpedia-owl%3Ayears%0D%0A%20%20%20%20dbpedia-owl%3Aaccess%20dbpedia-owl%3Athird%20dbpedia-owl%3Atime%20dbpedia-owl%3Aconstruction%0D%0A%20%20%20%20dbpedia-owl%3Aanniversary%20dbpedia-owl%3Aseries%20dbpedia-owl%3Alength%20dbpprop%3Asuspension%0D%0A%20%20%20%20dbpprop%3Abridge%20dbpprop%3Acrosses%20dbpprop%3ACity%20dbpprop%3Aconnecting%20dbpprop%3Alast%0D%0A%20%20%20%20dbpprop%3Athree%20dbpprop%3Asuspension%20dbpprop%3Abridges%20dbpprop%3Abuilt%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Fsubject%20%3Fproperty%20%3Fobject%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20geo%3Alat%20%3Flat%20%3Bgeo%3Along%20%3Flong%20.%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28%20-74.490898%20%3C%20%3Flong%20%26%26%20%3Flong%20%3C%20-73.490898%20%26%26%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2040.207222%20%3C%20%3Flat%20%20%26%26%20%3Flat%20%20%3C%20%2041.207222%20%29%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%28langMatches%28lang%28%3Flabel%29%2C%22EN%22%29%29%0D%0A%7D%20%0D%0Agroup%20by%20%3Fsubject%20%3Flabel%20%3Flat%20%3Flong%0D%0Aorder%20by%20desc%28%3FnumProperties%29%20%0D%0Alimit%2015&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: Very nice, and very quick! Thanks! :)